# Overcome Gmail security assessment for GAS apps

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

I have GAS app which uses Gmail API. I have been instructed to go for security assessment.
I don't send any secure data to 3rd party server. I read somewhere that Apps Script apps doesn't need to have security assessment unless I use URlFetchApp. Is that true ?

There are so many information flooding here are there. I am confused which is true. Is there any way I can overcome the security assessment ? Anybody here any experience with these assessments ?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: You mention you "don't send any secure data to 3rd party server". You are the third party. Do you send *anything* to your servers?

Comment: No, I don't. I use urlfetchapp though for payment processing.